# $B → A$ flat iff $\operatorname{Spec}A \rightarrow \operatorname{Spec}B$ flat.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

How to do it with the hint as Vakil says in [FOAG](http://math.stanford.edu/%7Evakil/216blog/FOAGjul3123public.pdf), Page 679?

> 24.2.F. EXERCISE. Show that a map of rings $B \rightarrow A$ is flat if and only if the corresponding morphism of schemes $\operatorname{Spec}A \rightarrow \operatorname{Spec}B$ is flat. More generally, if $B \rightarrow A$ is a map of rings, and $M$ is an $A$-module, show that $M$ is B-flat if and only if $\widetilde{M}$ is flat over Spec B. (Be careful: this requires more than merely invoking Proposition 24.2.3.) Hint: working indirectly in both directions is a good way to proceed. "Suppose $M_{\mathfrak{p}}$ is not $B_{\mathfrak{q}}$-flat. Then there is an exact sequence of $B_{\mathfrak{p}}$ modules (hence also B-modules) $0 \rightarrow N^{\prime} \rightarrow N \rightarrow N^{\prime \prime} \rightarrow 0$ such that..." "Suppose $M$ is not B-flat. Then there is an exact sequence of B-modules ..."

I get a proof from https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/00HT and [Prove that $B_{q}$ is flat over $B_{p}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/821140/prove-that-b-q-is-flat-over-b-p). Nevertheless, I am still wondering how Vakil’s hint work in proving this, rather than using the criteria like [A criterion of flat modules](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/283078/a-criterion-of-flat-modules) (Vakil mentions this two sections after this exercise, so I guess there are alternative solutions) I cannot see why working indirectly helps.

Prop 24.2.3 is:

> 24.2.3. Proposition (flatness is a stalk/prime-local property). An A-module $M$ is flat if and only if $M_{\mathfrak{p}}$ is a flat $A_{\mathfrak{p}}$-module for all prime ideals $\mathfrak{p} \subset A$.

and some definitions:

> 24.2.5. Definition: flat quasicoherent sheaves. We say that a quasicoherent sheaf $\mathscr{F}$ on a scheme $X$ is flat at $p \in X$ if $\mathscr{F}_p$ is a flat $\mathscr{O}_{X, p}$-module. We say that a quasicoherent sheaf $\mathscr{F}$ on a scheme $X$ is flat (over $X$ ) if it is flat at all $p \in X$. In light of Proposition 24.2.3, we can check this notion on an affine open cover of $X$.

> 24.2.6. Definition: flat morphism. Similarly, we say that a morphism of schemes $\pi: X \rightarrow Y$ is flat at $p \in X$ if $\mathscr{O}_{X, p}$ is a flat $\mathscr{O}_{Y, \pi(p)}$-module. We say that a morphism of schemes $\pi: X \rightarrow Y$ is flat if it is flat at all $p \in X$. We can check flatness locally on the source and target.
> We can combine these two definitions into a single fancy definition.

> 24.2.7. Definition: flat quasicoherent sheaf over a base. Suppose $\pi: X \rightarrow Y$ is a morphism of schemes, and $\mathscr{F}$ is a quasicoherent sheaf on $X$. We say that $\mathscr{F}$ is flat (over $Y$ ) at $p \in X$ if $\mathscr{F}_{p}$ is a flat $\mathscr{O}_{Y, \pi(p)}$-module. We say that $\mathscr{F}$ is flat (over $Y$ ) if it is flat at all $p \in X$

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What is Vakil's definition for flatness of sheaves of modules?

Comment: @LurchiDerLurch It means the stalk is flat after change of rings of stalks. I added the definitions now.